# Bayesian absolute loss function

Tags: bayesian

I came across a paper related to Bayesian decision theory where the absolute loss function is introduced somewhat straightforwardly. This is part of the result.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^a (a-\theta)\!  f(\theta|y) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$ = $\int_{-\infty}^a \!  f(\theta|y) \, \mathrm{d}\theta$ = $Pr(\theta\leq a|y)$

Since the upper limit of the integral depends on "a", differentiation under the integral sign can not be applied directly. I have been trying to adequate the leibniz rule to reach this result but I think the solution might be much more simpler.

Comment: Could you give a name (link) of this paper you are refering to?

Comment: This follows by expanding the first expression $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^a (a-\theta)  f(\theta\vert y)  \mathrm{d}\theta = \frac{\partial}{\partial a}a\int_{-\infty}^af(\theta\vert y)d\theta-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_{-\infty}^a \theta f(\theta \vert y)d\theta = \frac{\partial}{\partial a} aF(a\vert y)-af(a\vert y)=F(a\vert y)={\mathbb P}(\theta\leq a\vert y).$